# Rounding in awk while keeping the digit limit in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which contains decimal numbers, and I want to keep their 4 digits after integer part:

```
 file1.txt

1 A DD CD 1.3028377 CC
3 C JD CJ 0.647670 DD
4 CH FJF RHFH -3.220194 CCD
```

To round them to  4 digits:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"}{$4=sprintf("%.4f",$5)}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4}' file1.txt
```

It rounds as :

```
1 A DD CD 1.3028 1.3028
3 C JD CJ 0.6476 0.6476
4 CH FJF RHFH -3.2202 -3.2202
```

which is okay because there are no problematic numbers yet.

But if I round up to 3 decimals:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"}{$4=sprintf("%.3f",$5)}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4}' file1.txt



1 A DD CD 1.303 1.303
3 C JD CJ 0.650 0.650
4 CH FJF RHFH -3.22 -3.22
```

So I am losing the 3rd decimal in the last line as it round itself to a 0, and it is not written.

The expected output should be :

```
1 A DD CD 1.303 1.303
3 C JD CJ 0.650 0.650
4 CH FJF RHFH -3.220 -3.220
```

or it should print without any rounding :

```
1 A DD CD 1.302 1.302
3 C JD CJ 0.647 0.647
4 CH FJF RHFH -3.220 -3.220
```

How can I achieve these outputs?

EDIT :

As in the answer below, I can manage the expected output as :

```
awk '{OFS="\t"}{$4=sprintf("%.03f",$5)} 1 ' {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4}'
```

However, if I want to get the absolute values of these integers, the rounded numbers lose their integer digits as:

```
     awk '{OFS="\t"}{$4=sprintf("%.03f",$5)} 1 ' {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4}' file1.txt | awk '{OFS="\t"}{$NF=sprintf("%.03f",$NF){$NF=($NF<0)?-$NF:$NF}1' 

1 A DD CD 1.302 1.302
3 C JD CJ 0.647 0.647
4 CH FJF RHFH 3.22 3.22
```

As it should be :

```
1 A DD CD 1.302 1.302
3 C JD CJ 0.647 0.647
4 CH FJF RHFH 3.220 3.220
```

Comment: On `GNU Awk 4.1.65` I get -3.220. Also, your expression says `{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4}`, you are printing `$4` twice. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes it is okay, I have edited

Comment: It is GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: What's the output of `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", 3.2202}'`?

Comment: It is 3.220 ...

Comment: The code in your question cannot produce the output you say it does from the input you posted (your code changes $4 which on the first line is `CD` to a modified $5 and then prints $4 twice but the output shows the original $4 still present). Your script would also replace all blanks with tabs but your output does not have tabs between the fields. [edit] your question to show an actual **minimal** script running on actual input data and producing actual output so we can help you debug your problem. Right now it's not obvious how what you claim is happening could be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `awk`s command could help you on same.

***Solution 1st:*** Since OP was having input to change the last field only so this solution is according to that:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++){printf("%s ",$i)};printf("%.03f\n",$NF)}'    Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Only on a specific field then use following:

```
awk '{$5=sprintf("%.03f",$5)} 1 '  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
1 A DD CD 1.303
3 C JD CJ 0.648
4 CH FJF RHFH -3.220
```

Comment: No.. it rounds up and prints as 1.3 even though the rounded version is 1.300

Comment: @bapors, please check my updated command now and let me know on same.

Comment: I think it will work but can you please check my edit because my numbers are not in the last line (NF), they are in 5th column , and it has to print the number two times

Comment: @bapors, check my solution 2 now and let me know on same.

Comment: One question as, if I want to get the absolute values of these integers, I am still losing a decimal when it is 0. I have tried : ˝awk '{OFS="\t"}{$NF=sprintf("%.03f",$NF)}{$NF=($NF<0)?-$NF:$NF}1'˝

Comment: @bapors, not clear either please add in your post. Or open a new post in case it is different question.